# PHP - Getting an Hex Character code #x2f in strings instead of its symbol "/" (Slash)

Tags: php, xml, string, character-encoding, html-entities

I have generated the xml file using php but the issue is I am getting #x2f hex character code instead of its symbol slash (/) in description of content.

[Here](http://cash.infiniteloopcorp.com/hsjobs/vacancies/RSS.php) is the url to that xml file. You will see #x2f; code in description.

Screenshot to the code : [image]

I am trying to generate RSS feeds of jobs.

I have tried :

```
htmlentities(), htmlspecialchars_decode(), html_entity_decode, iconv()
```

php string functions but not success.

I have also searhed on Stack's previous questions but no success.

Thank you for your kind help.

Edit 1 (Code of PHP file):

```
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Hastings Jobs</title>
<description>Latest job vacancies in Hastings and St Leonards, East Sussex</description>
<link>http://hastingsjobs.net</link>
<pubDate>'.gmdate("D, j M Y h:i:s A").'</pubDate>';

    $JobQuery = new JobApis\Jobs\Client\Queries\ZiprecruiterQuery([
                        'api_key' => "APIKEY"
                    ]);
    $JobQuery->set('jobs_per_page', '10')->set('location','Hastings, UK')->set('radius_miles','5')->set('days_ago',2);
    $client = new JobApis\Jobs\Client\Providers\ZiprecruiterProvider($JobQuery);
    $jobs = $client->getJobs();
    $i=1;
    foreach($jobs->all() as $result)
    {
    $snippet=str_replace("&", "and", $result->__get('description'));
    $jobtitle=str_replace("&", "and", $result->__get('name'));
    $date = $result->__get('datePosted');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
    $date->modify('-5 hours');
    echo '<item><title>'.$jobtitle.'</title><description>'.htmlentities($snippet, ENT_XML1).'</description><guid>'.htmlEntities($date->format('D, d M Y, H:i:s T')).'</guid><link>'.htmlEntities($result->__get('url')).'</link><pubDate>'.$date->format('D, d M Y, H:i:s T').'</pubDate></item>';
     $i=$i+1;
     if($i==11) break;
}
echo '</channel>
</rss>';
```

Comment: How are you generating the file?

Comment: with header - header('Content-Type: text/xml');

Comment: The header doesn't generate XML. You say *"I've generated the XML file using PHP"* what I'm asking is how you did that.

Comment: yeah I am creating a xml file using php header which is telling compiler to compile the content as XML. I have put the url to the php file which is outputting as XML.

Comment: So you're not the one actually generating the XML you're getting it from somewhere else? What's the full code you're using besides the `header` bit?

Comment: I am putting php variables to xml tags and printing. Its I am generating.

Comment: Updated the question with the code.

Answer (score -1):

Use `htmlentities` with `ENT_XML1` flag

```
htmlentities($string, ENT_XML1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and used `html_entity_decode`

```
<?php
echo html_entity_decode($string);
?>
```